# Python function not passing variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting NameError: name 'currentYear' is not defined

I'm just trying to pass it down into the next function, not sure whats going on. Maybe I'm too tired at this point.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

```
def loopForData():
    currentYear = 1994
    for i in range(1, 2):
        currentYear += 1
        nfl_url = "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/"+str(currentYear)+"/index.htm"
        driver.get(nfl_url)
        data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="playoff_results"]/tbody')[0].text
        lenCheck(data, currentYear)


def lenCheck(data, currentyear):
    test = currentYear
    arr = ['WildCard', 'Division', 'ConfChamp', 'Superbowl', 'SuperBowl']
    counter = 0
    for word in data.split():
        if word in arr:
            counter += 1
    print(test)
```

Comment: you've spelled it ```currentyear``` and ```currentYear```, python is case-sensitive

Answer (score 3):

you passed currentyear and you used currentYear

Comment: solid thanks buddy, I'm done for the day, brain is clearly toast